# Cohomology ring of $U(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

As you know 
$$H^\ast (U(n);{\bf Z})=\bigwedge_{\bf Z}[x_1,x_3,...,x_{2n-1}]$$ 
where $|x_i|=i$

To prove this we use Leray-Hirsch Theorem for 
$$\tag{*}\ U(n-1)\rightarrow U(n)\rightarrow S^{2n-1}$$
 To do this we must show that for inclusion 
$$f:S^{2n-1} \rightarrow U(n)$$
where $f^\ast (\alpha)$ is generator of $H^{2n-1}(S^{2n-1})$.

How can we prove this? Thanks in advance.

### Answer

Here fiber is $U(n-1)$ so that the above statement is not true.

From Eq $(\ast)$ we have a lone exact seq. for homotopy so that $(U(n),U(n-1))$ is $(2n-3)$-connected.

For generator $x_{2k-1}\ (k=1, ... ,n-1)$ for $U(n-1)$, there exist 
$$i^\ast c_{2k-1}= x_{2k-1}$$ and 
$$c_{2k-1}\in H^\ast(U(n))$$ where 
$$i\colon U(n-1)\rightarrow U(n).$$

Comment: Dear user, What do you mean by "the inclusion $f$"?  The map between $U(n)$ and $S^{2n-1}$ goes the other way.  And what is $\alpha$? Regards,

Comment: I am sorry. I eddited. Please see answer paragraph in the above.

Comment: If I understand the question and you are happy to use the Serre spectral sequence I think this comes out pretty easily from the sparseness of the spectral sequence.